# Why does shape appears on click of canvas element after removing it?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

When I remove the object and click on canvas element , the removed shape re-appears and I am not able to select it also.

```
   var delete = function(){

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").fabric;

        canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to register an handler to object selection on canvas, then remove the object.

Check the runnable snippet below if could work for your needs:

```js
$(function() {
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')
  var operation = '';
  var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 20,
    fill: 'green',
    left: 100,
    top: 100
  });

  var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
    width: 20,
    height: 30,
    fill: 'blue',
    left: 50,
    top: 50
  });

  canvas.add(circle, triangle);
  canvas.on('object:selected', doOperationHandler);

  function doOperationHandler() {
    if (operation == 'remove') {
      remove();
    }
  }

  function remove() {
    canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject());
  }

  $('#btn_select').on('click', function() {
    operation = '';
  });

  $('#btn_delete').on('click', function() {
    operation = 'remove';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id='c'>
</canvas>

<button id='btn_select'>Select</button>
<button id='btn_delete'>Delete</button>
```